# Media Players (e.g. VLC) auto muting

Tags: sound, vlc, mute

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

Today I was listening to some audio using the default media player (Videos). I paused the player and watched a youtube video. When I went back to the Videos player, there was no sound, even when the volume switcher was turned up.

I installed VLC player to play my audio, which it did, but then everytime I switched a window to firefox and opened a Youtube video, VLC would automatically mute itself. Luckily with this one I could at least unmute it with the graphical interface, but this is really annoying and not a functionality I want.

Checking it again now and it seems that even when I close and re open VLC, it is automatically set to mute! Even when I don't switch windows.

Any ideas how to get rid of this 'feature'?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is just how VLC works by default in the newer version sadly.

I have looked at all the settings in VLC and can't find anything about "mute on startup" or anything similar.

Searching the web the only things I find are years old about people WANTING vlc to start muted on startup vs WANTING vlc to start unmuted.

Answer (score 0):

The newer version of VLC has an option in Tools -> preferences -> Audio called "output". It's set to "automatic" by default. Change this to PulseAudio or alsa or whichever sound output you use. This should fix the problem :)

Accy